# Hangman game - issues with looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to design a simple hangman game, and am currently having issues with looping this game. I am VERY new to Python, and am aware that there is probably quite a simple issue with this, but would appreciate any help.

Here is the code I currently have for the game:

```
import random
random_words = ["stationery", "notepad", "pencil", "paper","eraser","highlighter","stapler","sharpener"]
computer_choice = random.choice(random_words)
print("The number of letters in the word I have chosen is " +           str(len(computer_choice) + ".")

player_guess = None
guessed_letters = []
word_guessed = []

for letter in computer_choice:
    word_guessed.append("-")
    joined_word = None

player_guess = str(input("Please pick a letter you think is in the word I have chosen."))

attempts = (len(computer_choice)-1)

for letter in (0, len(computer_choice)):

if attempts != 0 and "-" in word_guessed:
    joined_word = "".join(word_guessed)
    print(joined_word)

    guessed_letters.append(player_guess)

    for letter in range(len(computer_choice)):
            if player_guess == computer_choice[letter]:
                word_guessed[letter] = user_input

            if player_guess not in computer_choice:
                attempts -= 1
                player_guess = str("Please try again. You have  " + str(attempts) + " attempts remaining.")

if "-" not in word_guessed:
print("Congratulations! {} was the word").format(computer_choice)

else:
print("Unlucky! The word was " + str(computer_choice) + "!")
```

Currently, the game does not loop, and simply cuts straight to the 'unlucky, the word was ___'. How do I fix this? What is the issue?

Comment: Could you double check your indentation? For instance, `if attempts != 0 and "-" in word_guessed:` appears right underneath the `for letter in (0, len(computer_choice)):`, and the final `if/else` bock seems borked as well (on a first look, at least)

Answer (score 1):

When you post the code, please ident it so it's easier to understand and for python to compile as that's essencial in the interpreter.

You code had some errors with the loop as in do not use a for loop to cycle through a simple repetition, use for to cycle through lists. For simple repetition use while. Also same variable in two nested for loops, get things complicated.

Also no need to cycle through every letter in yet another for loop, `in` operator will already check if character exists or not in word.

I created another way to find and replace the characters in the word, a little bit more straightforward I guess

```
import random
random_words = ["stationery", "notepad", "pencil", "paper","eraser","highlighter","stapler","sharpener"]
computer_choice = random.choice(random_words)
print("The number of letters in the word I have chosen is " + str(len(computer_choice)))
win = computer_choice #computer_choice will be destroyed later on
print(computer_choice)
guessed_letters = []
word_guessed = []

for letter in computer_choice:
    word_guessed.append("-")
joined_word = None

player_guess = input("Please pick a letter you think is in the word I have chosen.")

attempts = (len(computer_choice)+1)

x = 0
while x < len(computer_choice):
    x+=1

    if attempts != 0 and "-" in word_guessed:

        if player_guess in computer_choice:
            y=0
            while y < computer_choice.count(player_guess): #will count how many times guessed word is in string
                y+=1
                pos = computer_choice.find(player_guess) #return index of where the letter is
                word_guessed[pos] = player_guess #replaces word_guessed with letter in pos
                computer_choice = computer_choice.replace(player_guess,'#',1) #deletes so it won't find it again
            player_guess = "/"
        if player_guess not in computer_choice:
            attempts -= 1
            print("Please try again. You have  " + str(attempts) + " attempts remaining.")
        player_guess = input("Please pick a letter you think is in the word I have chosen.")
        joined_word = "".join(word_guessed)
        print(joined_word)
    else:
        break

if "-" not in word_guessed:
    print("Congratulations! %s was the word"%win)

else:
    print("Unlucky! The word was " + str(win) + "!")
```